# LocalNotificationSchedule not working on android react native v0.60

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-push-notification

localNotificationSchedule is not working react-native-push-notification while localNotification is working normally:

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    message: "Notification",
    date: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000),
    id: "1"
  });
```

"react-native": "0.60.5",

"react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.2"

updating AndroidManifest as intended in https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification,

any help what should be done to display notification using localNotificationSchedule()

Comment: In react 0.60.5; react-native-firebase [https://rnfirebase.io] was worked without any issue, If you are able to change react-native-push-notification to react-native-firebase it will greate.

Comment: @EL173 I'm obliged to use react-native-push-notification

Comment: have you found any solution?